# Nesting Static Partition under Dynamic Partition

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hive-partitions

In Hive why I am not allowed to nest a static partition under a dynamic partition?

for eg the below is allowed

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T PARTITION (ds='2010-03-03', hr)
SELECT key, value, /*ds,*/ hr FROM srcpart WHERE ds is not null and hr>10;
```

but this is not allowed

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE T PARTITION (ds, hr = 11)
SELECT key, value, ds/*, hr*/ FROM srcpart WHERE ds is not null and hr=11;
```

I find the official wiki page explanation (shown below) insufficient. Prefer a logical explanation or an explanation at underlying map-reduce level.

```
SP is a subpartition of a DP: should throw an error because partition column order determins directory hierarchy. We cannot change the hierarchy in DML
```

Comment: As an optimization, static partition will be created upfront rather during @ runtime. hence your  (ds, hr = 11) will not work becoz parent directory is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

That's a Hive design issue([specified here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions)):

> If there are multiple partitioning columns, their order is
>   significant since that translates to the directory structure in HDFS:
>   `partitioned by (ds string, dept int)` implies a directory structure of
>   `ds=2009-02-26/dept=2`.
>
> In a DML or DDL involving partitioned table,
>   if a subset of partitioning columns are specified (static), we should
>   throw an error if a dynamic partitioning column is lower.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> create table nzhang_part(a string) partitioned by (ds string, dept int);
> insert overwrite nzhang_part (dept=1)
>   select a, ds, dept from T
>   where dept=1 and ds is not null;
> ```

Comment: Thats not case here, The first partition is static while the 2nd layer is dynamic.